# Picking out specific values from a group in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, alter

This seems like such a simple problem, but I can't find a good solution.  I'm trying to select information from a slightly misformatted table.  Basically, wherever `sequence=0`, the `person_id` should actually be a `company_id`.  This `company_id` then applies to all the rows which have the same `group_id`.

Someone thought it was a good idea to format things this way instead of simply having a `company_id` column, but it makes trying to select by company very difficult.  It would make my programming much easier to simply add this extra column, and fix the formatting.

I want to turn something like this:

```
+----------+------------+-----------+----------+
| group_id | date       | person_id | sequence |
+----------+------------+-----------+----------+
|        1 | 2012-08-31 |        10 |        0 |
|        1 | 2012-08-31 |        11 |        1 |
|        1 | 2012-08-31 |        12 |        2 |
|        2 | 1999-04-16 |        10 |        0 |
|        2 | 1999-04-16 |        21 |        1 |
|        2 | 1999-04-16 |        22 |        2 |
|        2 | 1999-04-16 |        23 |        3 |
|        2 | 1999-04-16 |        24 |        4 |
|        3 | 2001-01-09 |        30 |        0 |
|        3 | 2001-01-09 |        31 |        1 |
|        3 | 2001-01-09 |        11 |        2 |
|        3 | 2001-01-09 |        12 |        3 |
+----------+------------+-----------+----------+
```

Into this:

```
+------------+----------+------------+-----------+----------+
| company_id | group_id | date       | person_id | sequence |
+------------+----------+------------+-----------+----------+
|         10 |        1 | 2012-08-31 |        11 |        1 |
|         10 |        1 | 2012-08-31 |        12 |        2 |
|         10 |        2 | 1999-04-16 |        21 |        1 |
|         10 |        2 | 1999-04-16 |        22 |        2 |
|         10 |        2 | 1999-04-16 |        23 |        3 |
|         10 |        2 | 1999-04-16 |        24 |        4 |
|         30 |        3 | 2001-01-09 |        31 |        1 |
|         30 |        3 | 2001-01-09 |        11 |        2 |
|         30 |        3 | 2001-01-09 |        12 |        3 |
+------------+----------+------------+-----------+----------+
```

The only way I can think of how to achieve this is with nested SELECT statements, which are very inefficient considering I have about 100M rows.  It's a one time fix though, so I don't mind letting it run overnight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you permanently want to change your table to include a `company_id` column then do this:

First alter the table and add the new column:

```
alter table your_table add company_id int;
```

Then update all rows to set the company to the `person_id = 0` for the group:

```
UPDATE your_table a 
JOIN your_table b ON a.group_id = b.group_id  
SET a.company_id = b.person_id
WHERE b.sequence = 0;
```

And finally remove the rows with `sequence = 0`:

```
DELETE FROM your_table WHERE sequence = 0;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9531e/1)

The end result will be:

```
| group_id |       date | person_id | sequence | company_id |
|----------|------------|-----------|----------|------------|
|        1 | 2012-08-31 |        11 |        1 |         10 |
|        1 | 2012-08-31 |        12 |        2 |         10 |
|        2 | 1999-04-16 |        21 |        1 |         10 |
|        2 | 1999-04-16 |        22 |        2 |         10 |
|        2 | 1999-04-16 |        23 |        3 |         10 |
|        2 | 1999-04-16 |        24 |        4 |         10 |
|        3 | 2001-01-09 |        31 |        1 |         30 |
|        3 | 2001-01-09 |        11 |        2 |         30 |
|        3 | 2001-01-09 |        12 |        3 |         30 |
```